# Trying to build something with what I'd call a 'living model' in Swift. Think I might be doing this wrong

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I'm trying to build what I'm going to describe as a 'living model'. Imagine I have a virtual creature, which has an energy attribute which slowly goes down or up over time, depending on it's current activity. And once it goes down to a certain level, it naturally goes to sleep. Then once it goes back up to a certain level, it wakes up naturally. And it might have an `exhausted` attribute, which is `true` if that energy is under its natural sleep level, and if it's also awake. These attributes changing - the activity, whether the creature is exhausted, all affect the appearance of the creature, and that appearance needs to know to change whenever those things change. Exhausted doesn't just change after a delay though, it changes when 'energy' reaches a certain point, or when the activity changes.

So you can see there's a few different concepts all working together, and doing this using regular Swift programming is giving me a knot which is currently quite loose, but slowly growing tighter and more complex.

So I need some advice on how to handle this in a way that isn't going to cause headaches and difficult-to-find issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the properties to represent the various points that things happen to the creature. Then, as Mr Beardsley suggests, use didSet on your energy property, and compare its value to the "action points". Finally, you can use NSTimer to reset the energy property at regular intervals.

This allows you to create several different creature instances with unique energy levels for which they fall asleep or become exhausted.

```
enum MonsterState {
    case Awake, Asleep, Exhausted
}

class Monster {
    var monsterState = MonsterState.Awake
    let drainRate: Int
    let pointOfExhaustion: Int

    var energy: Int {
        didSet {
            if energy <= pointOfExhaustion {
                monsterState = .Exhausted
            } else if energy <= 0 {
                monsterState = .Asleep
            }
        }
    }

    init(energy: Int, pointOfExhaustion: Int, drainRate: Int) {
        self.energy = energy
        self.pointOfExhaustion = pointOfExhaustion
        self.drainRate = drainRate
    }

    func weaken() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0,
            target: self, selector: "drainEnergyWithTimer:",
            userInfo: ["pointsPerSecond": drainRate], repeats: true)
    }

    func drainEnergyWithTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
        if let passedInfo = timer.userInfo as? [NSObject: AnyObject]{
            let energyDecrease = passedInfo["pointsPerSecond"] as! Int
            energy -= energyDecrease
        }

        if energy <= 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}

let godzilla = Monster(energy: 100, pointOfExhaustion: 12, drainRate: 3)
let mothra = Monster(energy: 150, pointOfExhaustion: 25, drainRate: 2)
godzilla.weaken()
mothra.weaken()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a implementation you can work with to get you started. Note, I used a struct, but you might change that to a class and inherit from SKSpriteNode if you are using Sprite Kit for your game.

```
enum CreatureState: Int {
    case Active = 50
    case Sleeping = 20
    case Exhausted = 10 
}

struct Creature {
    var energy: Int {
        didSet {
            switch self.state {
            case .Active:
                if energy < CreatureState.Active.rawValue {
                    self.state = .Sleeping
                }
                else if energy < CreatureState.Sleeping.rawValue {
                    self.state = .Exhausted
                }
            case .Sleeping:
                if energy > CreatureState.Sleeping.rawValue {
                    self.state = .Active
                }
            case .Exhausted:
                if energy > CreatureState.Active.rawValue {
                    self.state = .Active
                }
                else if energy > CreatureState.Active.rawValue {
                    self.state = .Sleeping
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var state: CreatureState

    init(energyLevel: Int, state: CreatureState) {
        self.energy = energyLevel
        self.state = state
    }
}
```

I modeled the different states of your creature as an Enumeration with associated values. You can change those to whatever values mark the change from one state to another.

By using the 'didSet' property observer on energy, it is possible to perform actions any time a new value for energy is set. Overall, we are able to model your requirements with only 2 properties.